# How to remove user session attribute saved in namespace 'foo'?

Tags: php, symfony1

To remove a user session attribute foobar' saved in the default name space, simply do this:

```
$user->getAttributeHolder()->remove('foobar');
```

How do you remove attribute foobar if it was saved in namespace foobar like this:

```
$user->setAttribute('foobar', 123, 'foo');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can specify the namespace like this :

```
$user->getAttributeHolder()->remove('foobar','','foo');
```